# C++ AMP Deque in parallel loop

Tags: c++, deque, c++-amp

I have a small problem with C++ AMP.
I need to use in parallel_for_each loop, double ended queue. When I am using `std::deque<int> V;` it is an error and I also know that it is unsafe.
There is concurrent_queue which is safe, but what about dequeue?

Comment: “what about dequeue?” – yes, what about it? What do you mean?

Comment: I need to use dequeue in parallel_for_each loop. But when i tryied to use std:deque it is an error. (for example V.push_back(idx);  made an error: 'void std::deque<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_front(const int &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Concurrency::index<1>' to 'int &&'. How to handle it?

Comment: Ah, you mean “deque”, not “dequeue”? (The former is a data structure, the latter is usually [an *action* on a (different) data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29)). In any case, as you’ve noticed yourself, *you cannot do that*. Even if you make the compiler error go away, you end up with a race condition. Don’t use `std::deque` here, use the `concurrent_queue`. That’s what it’s for, after all.

Comment: Thank You. the right question with i mention to ask is "how to use concurrent_queue as deque"? I mean that in deque You can use V.push_front V.push_back etc, and how to use it in concurrent_queue?

Comment: For that you should read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx) (which, by the way, was the first Google hit). The relevant function is `push`. Since this is a queue and not a double-ended queue, you can only push to one end.

Comment: Yes I understand, but the problem is that i need deque because i need to push also to second end .